# Canvas in android 2.3 isn't using GPU?

Tags: android, android-canvas, hardware-acceleration

From [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html):

> Beginning in Android 3.0 (API level 11), the Android 2D rendering
>   pipeline supports hardware acceleration, meaning that all drawing
>   operations that are performed on a View's canvas use the GPU.

but I found that in [ViewRoot source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread-release/core/java/android/view/ViewRoot.java) , there's a lot of stuff to do with EGL. 
Additionaly, I watched an [android video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UApv-ZMJ51g) made by RomainGuy and he said that no matter you use Canvas or OpenGL commands, eventually you're rendering on top of a opengl layer.

so my question is , why in 2.3 the drawing operations of canvas is not hardware accelerated? Or am i missing/misunderstanding something?

Comment: Back then I don't think there was a requirement for devices to even have a GPU, I think now Google requires it.  But they didn't say nothing was hardware accelerated in 9 and 10, they said starting in 11 everything was.

Comment: @GabeSechan, yes, seems they made it very unclear.